# How to handle encoding of an extraction rule in a Visual Studio Web Performance Test

Tags: visual-studio, web, character-encoding, performance-testing

I have a web performance test that is using extraction rules.  The extraction rules are working fine in that they are getting the string that I need, however the encoding is breaking.

I'm extracting a SignalR connection token in the negotiate command which contains "+" and "/" special characters.  No matter what combination I use for both:

Negotiate Extraction rule: HTML Decode - True/False
Query String Parameter: URL Encode - True/False

I can only get the "+" sign to properly encode, and I can't handle the "/" character.  So when I re-run the web performance test, I keep on passing the character "/" which is causing the error:

"ConnectionID is incorrect format"

What is the solution to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `string newText = UrlEncode(extractedText);`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use:  URL Encode = True on the Query String parameter that is using the extraction rule from a request earlier in the test.  This properly formats the characters + and /